# What is the maximum value for limit when using the Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, limit

What is the maximum value of the limit parameter when using the Facebook Graph API?

https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?limit=123

https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?limit=456

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As sad as it may be this is undocumented and was never fully described in documentation.

BTW, Sometimes using Graph Explorer i notice paging links have `5000` limit specified, sometimes it's much lesser value. It may or may not be consistent across different methods and objects.

Answer (score 1):

I had 5000 in my App and it was working just fine, but for a few users I was getting errors. After a few tests everything started to work again with 3000.