# facebook batch request to get all the photos

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-batch-request

I want to get all the photos of the user who gave permission to the app. Currently, I tried single and batch request of Graph API but it always paginates the results. Is there a seamless way to get all the objects without following pages?

ps: I'm using PHP-SDK so answering in php is the money :)

Comment: Have you tried setting the limit parameter?

Comment: Yes, and no matter how big number you give, it limits to some number less then what you set so it's not reliable, you can't do limit=1000000. I can't see in the documentation but via Graph API Explorer, you can verify. Related post is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108811/what-is-the-maximum-value-for-limit-when-using-the-facebook-graph-api

Answer (score -1):

I found out that giving limit=0 is solving the problem. It still generates paging object but they return empty data set. So, limit=0 returns the whole dataset in one shot.

Comment: I'm far from the topic so no way to verify your answer :(