# Get all names of people who shared a post on Facebook

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get basic information (names, ids) about users who shared a post. Now I have:

```
import facepy

long_access_token = "Access-token"

graph = facepy.GraphAPI(long_access_token)
g = graph.get('10153256675935268/sharedposts')

print len(g['data']) # outputs 10

for share in g['data']:
    print share['from']['name']
```

The problem, and I don't understand why, is that it gives information only about 10 people (when there are 276 shares for the [post](https://www.facebook.com/Macklemore/posts/10153256675935268)).

I tried to increase limit up to 200 ('10153256675935268/sharedposts?limit=200') it increased number of shares up to 45, but never it went to 276.

How I can get information about all people who shared a post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because some people didn't share this post **publicly**. If you don't befriend these sharers, you won't be able to get any information about their posts.

---

You can see that it is the same on [facebook.com/10153256675935268](https://www.facebook.com/Macklemore/posts/10153256675935268). By clicking "shares", just around 45 shares are displayed. By the way, it is said below the shared posts list:

> Some posts may not appear here because of their privacy settings.

Comment: OK. What about limit parameter. How should I pick it to get as many shares as possible? Does it have maximum value?

Comment: That's a [whole new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108811/what-is-the-maximum-value-for-limit-when-using-the-facebook-graph-api). In your case, I would set a limit to 500 (too much is unsafe, your query might timeout) and [loop using the "after" and "before" paging cursors](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.0#).

Comment: Got it. However, for some posts I can't get any data at all. For example for this one: https://www.facebook.com/zuck/posts/10101319050523971. Can I somehow extract this information?

Comment: I don't know, this is not about the shares anymore. Feel free to open **new** questions on SO, so that others might give you answers. ;) You current question looks like being answered, you shall [mark it as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: Sure. Here is a new thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23844233/empty-response-from-facebook-graph