# Empty response from Facebook Graph

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get counts and information about likes, comments, and shared of posts on Facebook. And even though it works in most cases, sometimes I receive "empty" JSON response from Graph API.

**Code:**

```
import facepy, pprint

long_access_token = "Access token"

graph = facepy.GraphAPI(long_access_token)
limit = 1
user_id = "4"
post_id = "10101319050523971"

g = graph.get(post_id + '/sharedposts?limit=%s' %(limit))
pprint.pprint(g)
```

**Output:**

```
{u'data': []}
```

Note that this [post](https://www.facebook.com/zuck/posts/10101319050523971) has more than 200K likes and 30K shares. In contrast a [post](https://www.facebook.com/zuck/posts/10101323506030101) with 30K likes and 2K shares works beautifully. So I assume it's an issue of the "size" of a post.

How can I handle posts with large number of likes, comments, shares? I want to get counts as well as information about users.

Comment: Interesting question. Little advice: prior to programming, you can notice that exact same behaviour just by using the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer). It is the easiest way to know whether the data you are looking for is available or not.

Comment: Which access token are you using? It may be that the page is restricted in some way and your access token can't see it

Comment: I use long access token that I generated for my app. I don't think it can't see it because I can extract info from other posts of the same user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you're not supposed to be able to get feed from zuck because he obviously not using your app.

You can call the POST_ID endpoint because the type of this post is a **link** type

[image]

Even though you can't retrieve feed from zuck:

[image]

But, you can get the public link shared by zuck:

[image]

This was the response i received from Facebook:

[image]

Comment: I still can't get any data on links for post 10101319050523971. What is it?

Comment: Post 10101319050523971 is not a link type, so you're not supposed to be able to get data. Unless zuck authorized your app with read_stream permission.

Comment: Post 10101323506030101 is a link type, that's why you can get the data without zuck's authorization. Is it clear for you?

Comment: Is link type is just a message with presence of some link?

Comment: You can test yourself with "me/links" endpoint, e.g. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Flinks&version=v2.0 and you will noticed this posts have a link behind message.

Comment: So how I can test what post is link type before checking its data?

Comment: Which API endpoint you call to get post id 10101319050523971 ? I doubt you can get the post id in the first place.

Comment: No, I was selecting it manually. You're saying that I can't even get it in the first place via API?

Comment: Yeah, you can't even get it in the first place via API. I don't believe you can get the post id via me/home endpoint or elsewhere.